# Filling two areas in tikz separated by a node symbol

Tags: tikz-pgf

I'm looking for a way to perfectly fit the colors in each area around this flower. At the moment, and by some brutal hacking coordinates to continue the lines after my node, i can only divide the areas by a straight line.

Is there a way to follow the curve imposed by the flower logo to separate and fill those areas ?

**MWE**

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{standalone}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{bclogo}
\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        %%Make a projector
        \fill[black] (0,0) rectangle (0.5,0.2);
        \fill[black] (0.5,0.1) -- (0.7,0) -- (0.7,0.2) -- cycle;

        %%Make a surface
        \draw (4,-2.2) -- (4,2.2);

        %%Draw the red light
        \filldraw[red, fill=red!10] (0.7,0) -- (4,-1.6) -- (4,1.8) -- (0.7,0.2);

        %%Draw the object to have anchor
        \node[inner sep=0pt] (objet) at (2.8,0) {\bcfleur};

        %%1st part of the inner area (red)
        \fill[red!30] (0.7,0.1) -- (objet.north) -- (objet.south) -- cycle;
        %%2nd part of the inner area (gray)
        \fill[gray!50] (objet.south) -- (objet.north) -- (4,0.5) -- (4,-0.62) -- cycle;

        %%redraw the lines around the inner area
        \draw[red] (0.7,0.1) -- (objet.south);
        \draw[red] (0.7,0.1) -- (objet.north);
        \draw[gray] (objet.south) -- (4,-0.62);
        \draw[gray] (objet.north) -- (4,0.5);

        %%redraw the object
        \node[inner sep=0pt] at (2.8,0) {\bcfleur};
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

**Current output :**

[image]

**Desired output :**

[image]

Comment: in principle, to follow the curve in node of `bclogo` package, you have to hack that package. This wastes time, and almost non-sense. I suggest using `pic` for flower, so you can follow the curve

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think there is no other way than finding the a curve that fits.

```
\documentclass[tikz,11pt,a4paper]{standalone}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{bclogo}
\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        %%Make a projector
        \fill[black] (0,0) rectangle (0.5,0.2);
        \fill[black] (0.5,0.1) -- (0.7,0) -- (0.7,0.2) -- cycle;

        %%Make a surface
        \draw (4,-2.2) -- (4,2.2);

        %%Draw the red light
        \filldraw[red, fill=red!10] (0.7,0) -- (4,-1.6) -- (4,1.8) -- (0.7,0.2);

        \pgfmathsetmacro{\myangle}{atan2(0.5,4)}
        %%1st part of the inner area (red)
        \draw[red,fill=red!30] (0.7,0.1) -- (-\myangle:2.78) to[out=78,in=-55] (\myangle:2.62) -- cycle;
        %%2nd part of the inner area (gray)
        \draw[gray,fill=gray!50] (4,-0.62) -- (-\myangle:2.78) to[out=78,in=-55] (\myangle:2.62) -- (4,0.5) ;

        %%redraw the object
        \node[inner sep=0pt] at (2.8,0) {\bcfleur};
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: That's what i'm afraid of. A logo like this is not a tikz object. Difficult to parse it. Thank you for the answer and in any event on having the perfect fit !